# iOS4 Enterprise App for Wireless Distribution

Tags: ios, distribution, wireless, over-the-air

My company recently joined iOS enterprise program to distribute in-house app to our employees. We choose over-the-air installation for our app and put the `.plist` and `.ipa` file inside our web server which are protected by our Id/password mechanism. It's means that you must log into our web site first then you can install the app. The whole process works fine when we put these files in open area(not protected by ID\password). However, once we put files behind protected it's showed "can not connect to example.com " and Xcode’s device console view shows

> “Jul 21 11:17:39 unknown itunesstored[385] : Could not load
>   download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "can not connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x1c551fb0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription= can not connect to iTunes Store}”.

I guess it’s because the session it’s not the same when we open the `itms-services://…` link which iOS called the process to install the app.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS installer is a sandboxed process that will only make an itms-services request.  There is absolutely no way of forcing the installer to authenticate to your backend server.  You will need to make your plist an unprotected resource or roll your own authentication mechanism based on values in the url.  Also, you can't use self-signed certificates to SSL protect your plist.